# Gigabyte Onboard graphics card heating up and then crashing

Tags: motherboard, graphics-card, crash, cooling

5 minutes after I turn on my PC the onboard graphics card is usually over 80° celsius and then crashes (random colors on screen, only way to get out is to just plug out the pc).

- I haven't installed any new drivers or added/changed hardware recently
- Everything went fine until yesterday

What should I do next? Do I have to buy a new mainboard right now?

There is no fan on the onboard graphics card, only a heatsink.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would try is to add a fan, bigger heat sink, and make sure your case is ventilated well.  Check for dust and lint build up.  The next would be to add a heatsink with a fan.  Those are the cheapest option.  If you have a free graphics slot on your motherboard, you could disable the onboard graphics card and use a new on installed in your free slot. Your mainboard is probably fine, and if you have been otherwise happy with it, I would keep it and just install a new graphics card.

Comment: I have a similar issue but I have both a graphics card and onboard graphics in hybrid SLI. Graphics card runs at normal temps but onboard graphics keeps getting hotter going past ~100 C. Nothing seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If this start of happening all of a sudden, you may want to reapply some thermal paste like ArcticSilver

Comment: AND you can get a new heatsink, a premium one like Zalman.

Answer (score 1):

If your graphics cards are over 2 years old, go into your case and give everything with fins or a fan a thorough blast of compressed air.  Those dust bunnies are to components, what parkas are for arctic explorers.  Dust bunnies = heat.